# Understanding how HTTP GET upgrades to Web Sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, http, websocket

I am misunderstanding how to set up a web socket connection between a client and a server.

In my mind, an `HTTP GET` request expects a response, and then that is the full lifetime of the request.
When talking about web sockets now I am reading that the server responds with a
`101 (Switching Protocols)` and then magically(?) opens a web socket connection to that client.
How, on the client-side, do they handle the (again, magic?) stream of data that the server may now send them?

In my mind a regular request may be executed as such:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://localhost/something");
request.Method = "GET";
request.GetResponse();
```

Even if that `GetResponse()` returned a `101`, what more has to be done on the client-side to receive data? On the server-side?

I am looking for a pointer to some documentation that highlights the actual implementation. I prefer to not use a library in a specific language as I want any client to be able to initiate a web socket connection through a normal `HTTP GET` request.

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` doesn't go low level enough to handle web sockets. You need to either find a client side library that does or write your own.

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) (The WebSocket Protocol) is the document for you to read. You can find the description about the opening handshake in [4. Opening Handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4).

It's written in Java (not in C#), but you can consult [nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client) prior to implementing your own WebSocket client library in C#.

Comment: Thanks, I have a feeling I may have to implement my own library for my needs.

Comment: @Pipeline there are already several open source .NET projects in this area. Search and you will find them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket` to access a WebSocket server.

What happens after that HTTP 101, is that the connection is not considered ASCII based anymore, and it is considered a binary connection, where the WebSocket framing protocol comes into action, that is why you need a client websocket component, because you cannot write directly on the socket, you have to frame the information in messages as the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) explains.

Writing you own client would be very didactic, but not very productive.